# Blister over stitches

Tags: surgery, neutering

Had my dog spayed a couple weeks ago. As of last night, the stitches were fine. This morning, I snapped this picture. The skin around the blister is taught and it does look filled with fluid. It doesn't seem to be bothering her right now. Do I need to take her to the vet on Monday?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, have your veterinarian take a look at this.

It may be nothing serious, but certainly the skin looks inflamed and bruised at that site, and best to have it looked at before it gets any worse, or becomes infected. She might have been chewing at the area, perhaps irritated by the stitches still there.

In the meantime, keep an e-collar on her to stop her licking at the area.

In any case, if the surgery was a couple weeks ago, you need to take her back in now to have those stitches removed. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with @Harry V. that this would benefit from veterinary attention. I just wanted to also add - because I know that finances can often be part of what we weigh when we wonder if we should bring our pet to the vet - that at least where I am (Northeast US) many vets consider post-op checks like this as included in the initial cost of the surgery you've already paid for.  When you call to schedule your appointment you could inquire if that's the case for your vet's practice as well.